# about the use of user control inside the aspx page

Tags: asp.net

I have one UserControl containing one dropdown list and one textbox.This usercontrol i'm using in my my web application inside aspx page.
So i have problem that if I put some text inside the textbox inside the usercontrol then the requiredfieldvalidator for the dropdown list should  be enabled at runtime otherwise it should be disabled.

Any help will be highly appreciable.....

Comment: You should show the ascx markup of the `UserControl`. Why do you think that the `UserControl` is responsible for the issue since both controls + Validator are in it?

Comment: i'm giving only one drop down and one textbox inside the usercontrol.and adding requiredfieldvalidator for the dropdown list which is disabled by default

Comment: please show your code.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want the `RequiredFieldValidator` to be active only if the user entered text into the `TextBox` i would recommend to use a [`CustomValidator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eee01cx%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) instead.

```
void ServerValidation (object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{     
   args.IsValid = TextBox1.Text.Length == 0 || DropDownList1.SelectedIndex != -1; 
}
```

It is possible to use a `CustomValidator` control without setting the `ControlToValidate` property.

A possible clientvalidation-function:

```
<script language="javascript">
   <!--
   function ClientValidate(source, arguments)
   {
      var txt = document.getElementById('<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>');
      var ddl = document.getElementById('<%= DropDownList1.ClientID %>');
      if (txt.length == 0)
         arguments.IsValid = true;
      else
         arguments.IsValid = ddl.selectedIndex >= 0;
   }
   // -->
</script>
```

You have to register it on the validator via `ClientValidationFunction` property:

```
<asp:CustomValidator Id="CustomValidator1" runat="server"
    ClientValidationFunction="ClientValidate" 
    OnServerValidate="ServerValidation">
</asp:CustomValidator>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.I'm working on it.Let u know if it is done

Comment: Hello Tim,One thing i have to ask??where this javascript client side validation function should be added?

Comment: The `CustomValidator` above contains the link to msdn where all is explained. You can use clientside-validation, therefore i've provided this javascriot function. You have to register it on the validator via `ClientValidationFunction` property(as mentioned). Edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

set CausesValidation  property to false, then validation won't fire by the dropdownlist.